# Use 4/4 + 2/4 versus 6/4 time signature

Tags: time-signatures, metal

I tried to understand and then transcribe the song "Halo on Fire" by Metallica (2016). I noticed there are two sections when the time signature changes from 4/4 to 6/5. I will use the [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbxH5S9_A3M&ab_channel=Metallica) as time reference.

- [3:42](https://youtu.be/WbxH5S9_A3M?t=222): Exactly at the beginning of the bridge (?) section where the mood of the song slightly changes. There is a measure of 6/4 when the rhythm guitar slides between the A and B power chords.
- [6:12](https://youtu.be/WbxH5S9_A3M?t=372): The rhythm guitar (and, as a consequence, the lead guitar) stays on a D power chord for 6 measures of 4/4. Then it moves to a C power chord for a single 6/4 measure.

My question is for both of the above points. When transcribing stuff like this, it is recommended to change to a 6/4 measure, or keep it as a 4/4 and adding a final 2/4 measure? Thank you.

Comment: I would write this as 4/4 with the occasional half bar of 2/4 when needed. That's clearly how the play and count it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So technically, 6/4 is taught to be a compound meter, being essentially the same thing as 6/8 (where there are two groupings of three notes, in this case eighth notes, creating the sound of a measure with two beats, where each beat is effectively divided into triplets).

The only difference between 6/4 and 6/8 in this case, is that the grouping of three eighth notes are replaced in the notation with groupings of three quarter notes, but these groupings of quarter notes still sound like triplets. (Using 6/4 instead of 6/8 can have implications in relation to the bpm marking or in relation to other time signatures, but an entire song in 6/8 would be essentially the same thing if it was notated in 6/4)

However, 6/4 being used in the context of a song in 4/4, where it represents a
measure of 4/4 that got extended by two extra quarter notes, is a totally valid use of this time signature.

2/4, when used in the context of a song in 4/4, is like a measure in the song getting cut short by two beats.

With this song, you could really notate it either of the ways you suggested, and I'd say either option works. However, notating these parts of the song with the 2/4 method seems to be more accurate to the music. This is because the song is primarily phrased in groupings of four measures (as is a lot of music), and we can use measures of 2/4 to continue our representation of that four measure phrase pattern.

By notating the phrase that starts at around 3:41 to 3:42 as 4/4 2/4 4/4 4/4, our notation would show this section as being a four measure phrase, with the second measure being cut short by two beats, which seems to be a very accurate representation of what is happening musically. (Notating this part as 6/4 4/4 4/4 would notate it as a three measure phrase instead, which would result in us losing the visual representation of this being a four measure phrase)

Likewise, notating the section at 6:12 using the 2/4 method instead of the 6/4 method also preserves the four measure phrase representation. In this way of notating, there are seven measures of 4/4 and one measure of 2/4. Added together, this is eight measures, resulting in two, four measure phrases. The first four measure phrase is all in 4/4, and then the second four measure phrase, ends with a measure of 2/4, representing that the last measure got cut short by two beats.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the details in the rhythm. Using 2/4 + 4/4 (or 4/4 + 2/4) is really just a 2/4 stuck in the middle. Using 6/4 implies two groupings of 3 quarter notes.